# Error when INSERT array into table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, mysqli

I am trying to insert an array into table (below):

```
$arr = implode(',',$_POST['name']); 
$sql = "INSERT INTO test (name) VALUES ($arr)";
$mysqli->query($sql);
```

but im getting this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object
```

Any idea what is going on?

Comment: Quote your values, check your connection and what's passing through.

Comment: not duplicate my friend... that post is about connection and mine is ok

Comment: Well non-object can mean a lot of things. Bad connection, not using the same API, wrong DB chosen, wrong table, wrong column, wrong POST; who knows. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything,  as well as `or die(mysqli_error($mysqli))` to `mysqli_query()`.

Comment: please echo the $sql show the result to us

Comment: *"not duplicate my friend... that post is about connection and mine is ok"* - You're using `$mysqli` in the question but your answer contains `$conn`.

Comment: The error message is pretty clear: you're trying to call a method on something that isn't an object. Figure out what `$mysqli` is and change your code to make sure that it's an object that has a `query` method (or change your code to not call that method).

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the mysqli_query

```
$arr = implode(',',$_POST['name']); 
$sql = "INSERT INTO teste (item) VALUES ('$arr')";
mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
```

Comment: You're welcome. That's a far cry from what you posted.